# Supposed linked list example, outputs an array looking form instead of the actual object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

Looking at a test code with linked lists in JavaScript below, the input parameters of the `addTwoNumbers()` function are objects. The actual object is shown when I stringified the parameter. Instead, a simple `console.log()` shows something that looks like an array but is surely not. The question here is why the simple `console.log()` didn't output the actual object as it should, i.e. https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3z5eafms5.

Am I missing something or is it just the platform that reforms the output in some way?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects)

Comment: @Konrad Hi, thanks, no its a different issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) And a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question (and not just dumped onto an external platform.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListNode` objects have a [`Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectcustom) method that is used by NodeJS's `console.log()`/`util.inspect()` to retrieve a representational object:

```js
const symbol = require('util').inspect.custom;
// or const symbol = Symbol.for('nodejs.util.inspect.custom')

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(l1));
// { [Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)] }

console.log(typeof symbol, symbol in l1);
// 'symbol', true

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 42;
  }
  [symbol]() {
    return [43];
  }
}

console.log(new Foo());
// [43]
```